# Foreach java 8 from list of String to String

Tags: java, spring-mvc, foreach, java-8

I have a member function that will retrieve all membershipId of a member(one member might have multiples of membershipId).After retrieve all membershipId using List,it will call the url like this.

This is my service:

```
RestRequest request = RestRequest.newBuilder()
                .url("/membership/" + membershipId + "/outlet")
                .get();
```

This is my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/favouriteStores", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public Object FavouriteStores(ModelMap modelMap,HttpSession session)throws  Exception {
          String memberId = "5677a7075e3f1b998fc7483b";


 List<Membership> membershipList= memberService.getMembershipByMemberId(memberId);

 List<String>  membershipIds = membershipList.stream().map(m->m.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
         String membershipId = membershipIds.toString();

        Set<Outlet> outletSet = membershipService.getOutletByMembershipId(membershipId);
```

My problem is it will transform the whole membershipId in **one url** like this
"membership/[12345, 54321]/outlet" 
It should be **two url** like "membership/[12345]/outlet" and "membership/[54321]/outlet"

I know we can use foreach to do that in controller,but i don't know how.Thanks for any helps.

Comment: First URL will be "membership/[12345]/outlet" or "membership/12345/outlet" ?

Comment: Hi,It should be "membership/12345/outlet"

Answer (score 3):

Try `map` method of [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) instead :
You can achieve this using `map` method of [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

```
Set<Outlet> outletSet = membershipIds.stream()
    .map(membershipService::getOutletByMembershipId)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Even you can combine your previous stream operations and omit creation of  intermediate list objects :

```
String memberId = "5677a7075e3f1b998fc7483b";

Set<Outlet> outletSet = memberService.getMembershipByMemberId(memberId)
    .stream()
    .map(Membership::getId)
    .map(membershipService::getOutletByMembershipId)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: It would be even better, to combine this with the first stream operation to get rid of those intermediate lists which are counteracting the purpose of streams.

Comment: Right. I was too focused on the area of question. I have updated my answer.